# Typing a prop based on the provided values for another prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

So i'm trying to figure out how to make the properties of an interface match the provided values for another interface.

e.g

```
interface IHeader: Array<{header: string, label: string}> 
interface IData: Array<{ /** props are values of header **/}>

//for example if the header is:
const columns: IHeader = [
  {header: "age", label: "Age"},
  {header:"name", label: "Name"},
  {header: "date", label: "Date"},
]
// Then the available props on data should be:
const data: IData = [
  {age: "24", name: "some guy", date: "monday"}, // OK - all props match the columns.header values
  {age: "24", name: "some guy"}, // ERROR: missing 'date'
  {age: "24", name: "some guy", date: "monday", location: "1234 street"} // ERROR: location is not a valid property
]
```

How would i go about writing a type definition that takes all the values of 'header' provided across the entire array and creates a property name for each unique one? or is this even possible

**Edit: digging deeper into the actual implementation i'm going for**

the suggestion in the comments below worked when 'columns' is defined, however i'm trying to get this typing to apply to props passed to a component. here's the implementation I have so far

**Page.ts**

```
export default function Page() {
return (
<Table
  columns={[
    {label: "name", ...otherProps}
    {label: "date", ...}
  ]}
  data:={[
    {name: "me", date: "monday"}
    {name: "me", date: "tuesday", location: "1234 some place"} // Does not throw compiler error for location: invalid prop
  ]}
)}
```

**Table.ts**

```
type Header = ReadonlyArray<{label: string, align: string}> 
type Data<T extends Header> = ReadonlyArray<Record<T[number]['label'], string>>
/**
* interface TableProps extends DefaultTableProps {
*  columns: Header,
*  data: Data<typeof columns> // Obviously wrong, but don't know what to put. compiler says 'cannot find columns' understandably
*}
**/
export default function Table(props: {columns: Header, data: Data<typeof columns>}) { // no compiler error but props are obviously not set right because Page.ts does not complain about erroneous props
  const headerColumns = props.headerColumns
  const data: Data<typeof headerColumns> = props.data
// other code, like setting a default orderBy for the table
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState<keyof Data<typeof headerColumns>>(dataKeys[0] as keyof Data<typeof headerColumns>);
return (
  {...table stuff}
)}
```

Ideally i would like to be able to define an interface that contains the correct typings for columns and data, and give it to the function export because i need to extend some default props, but i can settle for manually typing the object

```
export default function Table(props: TableProps) {...} // contains columns, data, default props defined in an interface elsewhere, and still warns the compiler when there's extra props in the data object-array
```

Comment: Would [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/mAQ4Xm) work for you?

Comment: gonna implement and give it a shot. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Oblosys Can you add few words why `as const` is needed? (because when I remove it the errors are gone). If you explain your snippet as answer even better (I will upvote)

Comment: Sure! I'll put something together in a bit. There's also a nice TypeScript 4.9 feature you can use here.

Comment: @Oblosys going to edit my question to dig deeper into the solution- I believe your suggestion got me 80% of the way there, now i'm just trying to figure out how to get the compiler to recognise that the provided props are wrong similar to how your example does it

Comment: @Oblosys in case you won't write an answer (due to possible edit by OP as he/she said), I would appreciate if you can leave a comment explaining why `as const` was needed. cheers. PS. Also after using `as const` isn't the type a tuple now? and when you pass it as `T extends Header` shouldn't it complain, does tuple extend array?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized there were two people in the comments. @Dsabadash I can wait with the answer until your edit, but if there are a lot of changes, maybe you could post it as a new question? (questions about generics often get quick answers)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I'll explain it. And tuples are assignable to arrays, but with `as const` it becomes a read-only tuple, which is only assignable to read-only arrays.

Comment: @Oblosys question is edited. it's mostly just extrapolating your answer to 'how to hand these types to a function component props'

Comment: @Oblosys My biggest confusion now comes if I remove `as const` suddenly the errors which you highlighted don't  show up anymore. About tuples vs arrays I meant when it says `T extends Header` I thought I could pass it something which extends array, does Tuple do so? @Dsabadash I agree with @Oblosys IMHO it is not good idea to substantially change question, after someone put effort into it.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I agree with both of you, however i don't believe that the question is 'substantially changed' just because the answer is right, but led to needing a touch more information about how to practically apply it to a component

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I posted an answer for the original and the React bonus question. Let me know if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the exact type information from `columns`, you'll need to modify the definition a bit, as the original `colums` has type `{header: string, label: string}[]`, which does not contain the actual `header` values anymore:

```
const columns = [
  { header: 'age', label: 'Age' },
  { header: 'name', label: 'Name' },
]
// const columns: {header: string, label: string}[]
```

One way to handle this is by narrowing the type of each object by declaring it read-only with `as const`:

```
const columns = [
  { header: 'age', label: 'Age' } as const,
  { header: 'name', label: 'Name' } as const,
]
// const columns: ({readonly header: "age", readonly label: "Age"} | {readonly header: "name", readonly label: "Name"})...
```

This preserves the literal type information, but is a bit awkward as each element needs a separate `as const`, so the easiest solution is to make the whole array read-only:

```
const columns = [
  { header: 'age', label: 'Age' },
  { header: 'name', label: 'Name' },
  { header: 'date', label: 'Date' },
] as const
// const columns: readonly [{readonly header: "age", readonly label: "Age"}, {readonly header: "name", readonly label: "...
```

This also turns it into a tuple type, but that's not relevant here as we're only interested in the union of the element types.

From `columns`, we can obtain the type of allowed keys by indexing with `number` (to get a union of array-element types) and then indexing with `'header'`

```
type ColumnKeys = typeof columns[number]['header']
// type ColumnKeys = "age" | "name" | "date"
```

We can do this generically and create an array of string records with:

```
type Header = ReadonlyArray<{ header: string; label: string }>
type Data<T extends Header> = ReadonlyArray<Record<T[number]['header'], string>>
```

Note that `Header` needs to be read-only, as `columns` will be a read-only array. `Data` doesn't strictly need to be read-only, but read-only arrays provide more type safety, and allow the type to be used for both mutable and read-only arrays, whereas a mutable array type cannot be use for a read-only array.

Using `Data`, we can now use `Data<typeof columns>` to get errors in all the right places:

```
type ColumnData = Data<typeof columns>
const data: ColumnData = [
  {age: "24", name: "some guy", date: "monday"}, // OK
  {age: "24", name: "some guy"}, // ERROR: Property 'date' is missing in type
  {age: "24", name: "some guy", date: "monday", location: "1234 street"}
                                                // ERROR: 'location' does not exist in type
]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wORM6W)

It's also possible to use `Data` in React, but you will need to make the `Table` component generic:

```
function Table<H extends Header>(props: { columns: H, data: Data<H> }) {
  return <div></div>
}
```

and make sure to use `as const` for the `columns` prop:

```
<Table
  columns={
    [
      { label: 'name', align: 'left' },
      { label: 'date', align: 'left' },
    ] as const
  }
  data={[
    { name: 'me', date: 'monday' },
    { name: 'me', date: 'tuesday', location: '1234 some place' },
                                   // ERROR
  ]}
/>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLy7ZW)

Small update: Accidentally omitting `as const` in the `columns` prop will disable key type checking for `data`. If this turns out to be problematic, you could consider using a workaround like this:

```
type Data<T extends Header> =
  T extends Array<unknown>
  ? "ERROR: please use 'as const' in columns prop"
  : ReadonlyArray<Record<T[number]['label'], string>>
```

It's not ideal, but it will trigger an error at `data` if `columns` is a mutable array:

```
Type '({ name: string; date: string; } | { name: string;
date: string; location: string; })[]' is not assignable to type
'"ERROR: please use 'as const' in columns prop"'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKRdMm)

Comment: this is 100% exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the detailed answer, and for humouring my additional request to the original question. Bravo!

Comment: @Oblosys you needed `as const` to iterate over `"age" | "name" | "date"` right? otherwise it couldn't see them because it thought it was array with some objects right? I think I see it. The only question I think I have again about this: `T extends Header`, `Header` is array right, so can you pass Tuple here? does Tuple *extend* array? (bit new to TS)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yes a tuple extends an array, but the `as const` here is just to prevent TypeScript from inferring the wide `string` type for the `header` properties. We're not really using any tuple behavior here.